# Word for relative position

Tags: single-word-requests, prepositions

I believe there is a special term for words that convey relative position but I cannot seem to remember or find what it is.

For example Sam is ***behind*** Mitch in the queue.

Comment: I think this question needs expanding.

Comment: Have a look at the [Deixis Lectures](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html), especially Lecture 2: [Space](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/2-Space.pdf).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are often called *[spatial prepositions](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22spatial+prepositions%22)*.